# How do I group by a second order belongs_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grouping

I have a fairly simple problem in Ruby on Rails. I have three models: States, Cities & Stadiums

```
State has_many cities
City belongs_to State
City has_many Stadiums
Stadium belongs_to City
```

Stadium has a `city_id` column. City has a `state_id` column. Stadium does *not* have a `state_id` column. I can access state from stadium by `stadium.city.state`

I would like to perform a group count to count how many Stadiums there are in a State, similar to the below:

```
Stadium.group(:city).count
```

which works fine. In other words, I want to do something like this

```
Stadium.group(:state).count
```

, which doesn't work. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Add a has_many :stadiums to state, belongs_to :state to stadium and add a state_id column to Stadium.

Comment: Thanks. I know that would work, and I guess I should have stated that in the question, but adding that does not make development logical sense. Then I have to update two values (state and city) when I update city etc. A city is always in a specific state so the logic shouldn't belong to Stadium, if you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible in vanilla rails. You might be able to do it with a crafted SQL statement.

Alternatively, you can use the array method but may not be as performant...

```
Stadium.all.group_by(&:state).count
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid so but the group_by method only counted the total number of State (which was unexpected). Then again it did some 100+ requests so it won't be interesting anyway as I am doing it all to optimize performance.